# Opencart 2.0.3.1 clear cart on login to prevent duplicate items in cart

Tags: opencart

Opencart version 2.0.3.1

I would like the items in the customer cart database to be cleared on login and only the items in the current session cart retained. So if a customer returns to the website, adds items to the cart, goes to checkout, logs in, only the items from the current session are in the cart, none from a previous session.

I believe it may be resolved in this section of code, but I am not sure.

in file system/library/customer.php

```
if ($customer_query->row['cart'] && is_string($customer_query->row['cart'])) {
    $cart = unserialize($customer_query->row['cart']);

    foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->session->data['cart'])) {
            $this->session->data['cart'][$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->session->data['cart'][$key] += $value;
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: the question you linked isn't describing an issue, it's just asking for clarification on how the process works.  if the user logs in their old cart is loaded from the database.  are you saying you don't want to load previously saved cart?

Comment: When a customer logs in, their current session cart is combined with their cart from the database, resulting in duplicate items in cart.

Comment: yes, that is how it's supposed to work.  if you want it to work a different way, you need to be specific about what you're after.

Comment: I would like the items in customer cart database to be cleared on login and the current session cart retained. So if a customer returns to the website, adds items to the cart, goes to checkout, logs in, only the items from the current session are in the cart, none from a previous session.

Comment: I believe part of that code is needed to apply the current sessions cart on login. I am just not sure which part.

Comment: ok. can you tell me what this part of the code is doing?                      foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->session->data['cart'])) {
            $this->session->data['cart'][$key] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->session->data['cart'][$key] += $value;